# Adding ImageIcon to already visible GUI on button click

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm a bit confused as to why my program isn't working. I am trying to add a image to the frame when I click the button. I have verified in java that the file exists and it can find the photo. I have also verified that the button works. But when I compile and click the button it does nothing at all...if someone could guide me in the correct direction it would be much appreciated.

```
package gamePractice;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class window {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ex");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setText("Press Me");

        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                     if(e.getSource() == button) {
                        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("t.jpg"));
                        JLabel stickLabel = new JLabel("yes", img, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                        panel2.add(stickLabel);
                        frame.add(panel2);
                      }
               }
         });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding Components to an already visible container - you need to call let the `LayoutManager` know about the change by calling `revalidate` followed by `repaint`

```
panel2.add(stickLabel);
frame.add(panel2);
panel2.revalidate();
panel2.repaint();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly

Comment: but JPanel panel = new JPanel(); with JButton button = new JButton(); can dissapears forever, because JFrame uses BorderLayout

Comment: Since a `JLabel` with no image icon or text and no visible is effectively invisible, it would work better to declare the label as a class attribute and add it during frame initialisation. Then in the `actionPerformed(..)` method, set the icon. While adding components during run-time is possible, it is not the most optimal way to go about it (especially not in this case).

Answer (score 4):

- [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) uses [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) (only one `JComponent` can be placed to `CENTER` area)
- your [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) replaces `JPanel panel = new JPanel();` with  `JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();`, then `JButton button = new JButton();` can dissapears,

then there are two options, note [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) uses [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)

1. (correct) to add `JLabel` to `JPanel`, change `LayoutManager` to `JPanel` by using `BorderLayout`, load `ImageIcon` to the local variable, inside `ActionListener` to call `JLabel.setText()` and `JLabel.setIcon()`
2. (replacing content) call `revalidate();` and `repaint();` to `JFrame`, but `JPanel panel = new JPanel();` with `JButton button = new JButton();` can dissapears forever,